# Copying from One Dynamically Allocated Array to Another C++

Tags: c++, memory, dynamic-arrays

This seems like it should have a super easy solution, but I just can't figure it out.  I am simply creating a resized array and trying to copy all the original values over, and then finally deleting the old array to free the memory.

```
void ResizeArray(int *orig, int size) {
    int *resized = new int[size * 2]; 
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i ++)
        resized[i] = orig[i];
    delete [] orig;
    orig = resized;
}
```

What seems to be happening here is that `resized[i] = orig[i]` is copying values by reference rather than value, as printing orig after it gets resized returns a bunch of junk values unless I comment out `delete [] orig`. How can I make a deep copy from orig to resized, or is there some other problem that I am facing? I do not want to use std::vector.

Comment: Note that there is no such thing as "copying values by reference".  Either you're creating a new reference to the same data or your are copying.

Comment: Even if you don't want to use `std::vector`, you would gain a lot by wrapping this in a class so that clients can pass around an invariant object and not have to manage the fact that the implementation pointer is changing with every resize.  :-/

Comment: As an optimization, you could copy the array contents with memcpy. I checked with godbolt and neither gcc nor clang replace the copy loop with memcpy (I thought they do that sometimes these days, but not here).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Remember, parameters in C++ are passed by value. You are assigning `resized` to a *copy* of the pointer that was passed to you, the pointer outside the function remains the same.

You should either use a double indirection (or a "double pointer", i.e. a pointer to a pointer to `int`):

```
void ResizeArray(int **orig, int size) {
    int *resized = new int[size * 2]; 
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i ++)
        resized[i] = (*orig)[i];
    delete [] *orig;
    *orig = resized;
}
```

or a reference to the pointer:

```
void ResizeArray(int *&orig, int size) {
    int *resized = new int[size * 2]; 
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i ++)
        resized[i] = orig[i];
    delete [] orig;
    orig = resized;
}
```

By the way, for array sizes you should use the type `std::size_t` from `<cstddef>` - it is guaranteed to hold the size for any object and makes clear that we are dealing with the size of an object.

Comment: +1 The other option is to return the new array using... the return value.

Comment: @AndréCaron: that's an option too, but I think that these forms suit better the indented use.

Comment: As a point of clarification, by "double pointer" the respondent means "double indirection".  When I first read it, I was confused why he wanted to substitute `double *` for `int *`.

Answer (score 3):

I highly suggest replacing the arrays with `std::vector<int>`.  This data structure will resize as needed *and the resizing has already been tested.*

Comment: While `vectors` in general are something interesting, there also exist a variety of reason against them. Thus, your answer is opinion-based and rather a comment than an actual answer to OP's problem.

Comment: @Markus: One could say the same about arrays.  There also exists a variety of reasons against them, thus the OP's issue is opinion based and should be closed (and maybe deleted).

Answer (score 2):

`orig` must be a pointer to a pointer to assign it to `resized`:

```
int **orig;
*orig = resized;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm copying a dynamic array.

```
    #include <iostream>

    void FillArray(int* const arr, const int size)
    {
       for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
       {
           arr[i] = rand() % 10;
       }
    }

    void ShowArray(int* const arr, const int size)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            std::cout << arr[i] << '\t';
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    int main()
    {
        int size = 10;
        int *arr1 = new int [size];
        int *arr2 = new int [size];

        FillArray(arr1, size);
        FillArray(arr2, size);

        std::cout << "arr1 = ";
        ShowArray(arr1, size);
        std::cout << "arr2 = ";
        ShowArray(arr2, size);

        delete [] arr1;
        arr1 = new int [size];
        for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            arr1[i] = arr2[i];
        }

        std::cout << "==========================" << std::endl;

        std::cout << "arr1 = ";
        ShowArray(arr1, size);
        std::cout << "arr2 = ";
        ShowArray(arr2, size);

        delete [] arr1;
        delete [] arr2;
    }
```