# how to pass array with *& in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, function, memory, reference

I read the [dynamic array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8056746/copying-from-one-dynamically-allocated-array-to-another-c) and use it, but i have a bit question:
When i put following format in prototype:

```
void mmyfunc(int *& myArray)
{
 //implementation
}
```

1.if i pass an array to it, how to call it? because i get :

```
no matching function for call to
```

2.When i use the following implementation :

```
void NetworkSocket::resizeArray (int *&orig, int index, int size)
{
    int *resized =  new  int[size];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        if ( i == index )
            i++;

        resized[i] = orig[i];
    }
    delete [] orig;
    orig = (int *)new int[size];
    orig = resized;
}
```

i get seg fault in delete [] line.

Comment: How are you passing an "array" to it? Also, this code is leaks and segfaults all over: why go out of your way to get extra trouble? Use `std::vector`.

Comment: You left out the most important part of the code ... how you call it.

Answer (score 1):

I'll just assume by array you mean

```
int x[16];
```

and you call the function as

```
resizeArray (x, ...)
```

So `delete[]`-ing it explicitly results in undefined behavior, because it wasn't allocated with `new[]`. Moreover, `x` resides in automatic memory, so it gets cleaned up by itself. Moreover moreover, you can't re-assign arrays. **Arrays are not pointers**. They decay to pointers when passed as arguments.

If you declared the *array* as

```
int* x = new int[16];
```

then your approach would work. But not quite C++ yet.

You can just use a `std::vector` and `resize()`. Don't re-invent the wheel (unless this is an assignment).

EDIT: Just spotted this:

```
orig = (int *)new int[size];
orig = resized;
```

will leak. Remove the extra `new[]`.

EDIT 2:

What's

```
if ( i == index )
        i++;
```

supposed to do?

Comment: I would have put the `vector` advice first, but that's just me.

Comment: @EtiennedeMartel could be for educational purposes.

Comment: "then your approach would work"... The general approach yes, but not the current implementation.